# How do I make a 3D bounding box on a SkinnedMesh object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, character, bounding-box

I need to make a 3D bounding box around a SkinnedMesh renderer object for Unity.  I need to print the vertices to the screen or a JSON file for export.  Would you happen to know the key steps or even offer a code snippet for the bounding box part.  I can figure out how to get the data out of the engine.

Thanks for the help!

Brian

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked around the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SkinnedMeshRenderer.html) and found out that the `SkinnedMeshRenderer` class already has the bounds property, meaning that you probably only need to access it without having to create it.

Also in the [`Mesh.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-bounds.html) and [`Renderer.Bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html) documentations, there are a couple of snippets I belive could be helpful.